# Different types of Facebook open graph story?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Are there different types of open graph stories on Facebook?

I have just gone through this tutorial

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/#step7

And the result I end up with at the end is a post like this

[image]

However, I would like my post to look more like this

[image]

How can I achieve this. My app is on iOS, is it that only Facebook apps can make posts like the one above?

Comment: Have u figured out how to achieve what u want? Do u mind sharing with me as I'm stucked in integrating open graph to my games as well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a different description that the title. Here you have "Beat" twice it's why you have the url shown instead of a description.

The size of the asset cannot be changed by yourself, you must provide a big asset (600*600 for instance) but facebook will show the big or small asset depending on the quality of your story.

KingsRoad use explicit sharing: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/explicit-sharing/

which is a good idea if you want big assets, because this king of stories are user-generated (so have a great value)

Comment: Great, answer, thank you. Wish I could upvote more than once :)

Comment: I tried changing the title and the description but it still only displays the url. Any idea why that might be? Here is the url I'm currently trying to use https://hidden-castle-7245.herokuapp.com/opengraphobject.php?fb:app_id=554329451276476&fb:explicitly_shared=true
&og:type=gopiratestd:boss
&og:title=Charizard&og:description=%22Whatever%22
&og:image=http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/beautiful_cat_picture_6_168770.jpg
&body=Something